# Automatically Fill In Info From Row Onto Another Page

Tags: excel, autocomplete, fetch, invoice

I'm creating a quick invoice log in Excel. It consists of 2 pages, the first of which is the log, listing all of my employers, jobs, work done, total invoiced and invoice number in order of date, and the second page is an invoice which I will save/print as a PDF to send to my employer at the end of the job.

What I want to do is have the second page automatically update information depending on which invoice number I type in.

I'll do my best to explain an example:

I have an invoice number "0001" in the log which has employer "Mr. Smith", job details "Top Secret", hours "10" charged at "$10/hour", total to invoice "$100" and the date of which I am sending an invoice.

On the second page I have some blank fields labelled "Invoice", "To", "Job Details", "Hours", "Charged At" and "Date Invoiced". I want to be able to input "0001" into the "Invoice" field and for it to automatically gather the rest of the information for the other cells. This way, if I type "0002", the information should change and correspond to my second job in the log.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? If you need a better explanation I'll do my best.

Comment: Your question is a bit too vague. You will need VBA to fetch the info and append it as a new line on the other sheet but it does not look like you know about VBA at all. You probably need a tutorial more than an answer on SO which needs to be directed.

Comment: post screenshot or link of 2 pages to give us idea about the structure of your data.